# Use of unresolved identifier 'GridItem'

Tags: ios, swift, gridview, swiftui

I am new to SiftUI, I want to build grid layout

```
 let layout = [
    GridItem()
 ]
```

I am getting *Use of unresolved identifier 'GridItem'* Error,
for LazyHGrid and LazyVGrid also same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you import SwiftUI for this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check list:

1. Everything related to Grid is in SwiftUI 2.0 so you must use **Xcode 12** / iOS 14 / macOS 10.16
2. If you have combined UIKit/SwiftUI project make sure your module has `import SwiftUI`